# MongoDB (Mongoose & Mongo Client PHP) search in concat field

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given a structure like `{ name: String, middlename: String, lastname: String }` is there a way in mongo both mongoose for node and in php to search a term in the concatenation of the fields, for example in mysql i can do something like

```
select * from persons 
    where concat_ws(' ',name, middlename, lastname) like '%John A%' OR
    concat_ws(' ',lastname, middlename, name) like '%John A%'
    group by id
```

this way i dont need to explicitly make inputs for every field just one but i dont see how to accomplish something like that in mongo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator in the `find()` query:

```
db.persons.find({$where:function(){
    var search = /John A/;
    var matchA = (this.name+" "+this.middlename+" "+this.lastname).match(search);
    var matchB = (this.lastname+" "+this.middlename+" "+this.name).match(search);
    return !!(matchA || matchB);
}})
```

or, you could aggregate the results.

- `Project` two extra fields, which contain the concatenated value.(use [$concat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) operator.)
- `Match` using a regular expression pattern.([SQL to Mongo Mapping chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/).)

MongoDb aggregation pipeline:

```
var search = /John A/;
db.persons.aggregate([
{$project:{"concat_name_a":{$concat:["$name"," ","$middlename"," ","$lastname"]},
           "concat_name_b":{$concat:["$lastname"," ","$middlename"," ","$name"]},
           "name":1,"middlename":1,"lastname":1}},
{$match:{$or:[{"concat_name_a":search},{"concat_name_b":search}]}},
{$project:{"name":1,"middlename":1,"lastname":1}}
])
```

Going for either of the approaches would be fine here, since both the approaches cannot make use of any indexes on the collection.

Comment: Just `return !!(matchA || matchB)` is enough.

Comment: @thefourtheye - thanks for pointing that out. Now the code looks cleaner.